# mdadm RAID 6 rebuild when remaining drive(s) have bad sectors

Tags: software-raid, mdadm

I'm setting up a system at work to store some critical data. I will be using 4 x 1TB drives to create RAID6 via mdadm. I did lots of reading and can't find a definite answer to my question:

In a 4 drive RAID 6 setup one drive dies (lets say nr 1).
I will replace the dead drive and issue the rebuild command.
For argument sake drive nr 4 has a bad sector located at 15000.
How will mdadm handle it when it gets there ?

Will it try to read the bad sector and eventually give up and break the entire array ?

Will it recalculate the non-readable data from a different drive (2 and 3) via parity and rebuild the array without any problem?

Is there a definite answer to this ?

Also what would be the case when 2 drives would fail (lets say nr 1 and 2) and one of the remaining drives (nr 4) would have a bad block at 10000. Would that fail to rebuild regardless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll fail the second drive out of the array, and then continue rebuilding onto the new disk, using the data and parity information from the two still-live drives to recreate the missing data.

If one of those two remaining drives has a faulty sector further on, though... DOOOOOM.  You can, in theory, re-add the drive that had the fault earlier, and then continue the rebuild with the data from those two drives, but I'd be breaking out the backup tapes at that point, because you're having a *really* bad day.

Comment: Ok. So that is not good is it. What about software RAID 10? Will it fail if the other drive from the Mirror set will have one bad sector ?  Will TLER help at all ?

I'm thinking of maybe create a RAID 10 using 6 drives.

RAID 0
with 2 sets of RAID 1 (3 drives each)
Would that be a bit better ?

Comment: ServerFault isn't a discussion forum.  If you have other questions, it is best to ask them as new questions.